# Basic java for creating object

Tags: java

I m new to java,

Now i m learning java from this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

When i come to know about objects and class,

First part:

```
class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }
}
```

Here created one class name "Bicycle" without main method, and it contains fields and methods.

second part:

```
class BicycleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on 
        // those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```

Here it contains main method and created two objects, but

why here created another one class "BicycleDemo"

I just confused, It is simple question,

If anyone explain me, As beginners like me, it will help.

Thanks,

Comment: thanks for all answers  and comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BicycleDemo** contains the `public static void main (String [] args)` method, which is like the entry point for all Java programs.

Essentially, the **BicycleDemo** acts as a *driver class* for you to test the functions of the **Bicycle** class.

Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) to understand why is there a **BicycleDemo**

Combined into one **BicycleDemo.java**

```
class BicycleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}

class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) { cadence = newValue; }

    void changeGear(int newValue) { gear = newValue; }

    void speedUp(int increment) { speed = speed + increment; }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) { speed = speed - decrement; }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" + cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** `main` method inside Bicycle

```
class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) { cadence = newValue; }

    void changeGear(int newValue) { gear = newValue; }

    void speedUp(int increment) { speed = speed + increment; }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) { speed = speed - decrement; }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" + cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```

Comment: may i know, what is driver class? so we need two classes for creating object right?

Comment: @sandhu: You don't *have* to have two classes - it *could* all be in the `Bicycle` class... but one class creating instances of another is a very common scenario.

Comment: @sandhu You can think of `BicycleDemo` as a container for all your `Bicycle` objects? So it's like you have created a bunch of `Bicycle`, and you need a place to test whether those `Bicycle` function properly.

Comment: okay.. @Gosu: can assemble the my two separate sections of code.?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is possible to create object and main method without BicyleDemo class?

Comment: @sandhu: Yes, you could just put the `main` method in the `Bicycle` class. It wouldn't be terribly nice to do so, but you could.

Comment: @sandhu All inside one .java file, BicycleDemo.java. Not entirely sure why you would choose to do that, but wouldn't hurt knowing how it can be done.

Comment: @JonSkeet: can you show me code view as you said...?

Comment: @sandhu: No - instead, you should explain what you've tried. Moving a method from one class into another shouldn't require a demo. I suspect at this stage you'd be better off continuing to read the tutorial, or supplementing it with a good book. Stack Overflow is good for specific problems, but it's not a good way of learning the basics of the language.

Comment: @sandhu Listen to JonSkeet and read a book! Best way to understand is to read up on it, and try it out for yourself.

Comment: @gosu: according to option 2 ans, it have one class.. it is easy to understand right.. so only my question is, why we use two classes unnecessary? ...

Comment: @sandhu Take a look @ RiteshK's answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that if you put everything into one class, you have to worry about everything at once when you're writing new code. This may work for small projects, but for huge applications (we're talking hundreds of thousands of lines), this quickly becomes next to impossible.

To solve this issue, you break up pieces of functionality into their own classes and encapsulate all the logic. Then when you want to work on the class, you don't need to think about what else is going on in the code. You can just focus on that small piece of code. This is invaluable for working efficiently, however it's hard to appreciate without working on applications that are huge.

Of course there are countless other benefits to breaking your code into smaller pieces: the code is more maintainable, more testable, more resusable, etc., but to me the largest benefit is that it makes massive programs manageable by reducing the amount of code you need to think about at one time.

Comment: thanks @RiteshK: your answer is useful for me.. okay.. how save program, BicycleDemo.java or Bicycle.java?

Answer (score 1):

BicycleDemo is created to show you how to create an object, to explain encapsulation concept. Now you have access to different Bicycles.

Answer (score 1):

Bicycle is the class where you define your bicycle, that permit you to create lot of bicycle when you instantiate it.

BicycleDemo contains the main method of your program, commonly call 'entry point'. 
In this class you write what your program will do with your bicycles.

Answer (score 1):

Here `BicycleDemo` is a controller class. It has a `main` function which is an entry point. From this class you can create any number of objects for any class. You could also add `main` function in your `Bicycle` Class. Writing separate beans is best practices

Answer (score 0):

Since everything in Java is an object and has to be declared in a class, there is no way to get around first declaring a class to do the most simple thing. `HelloWorld.java` program:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Of course another option will be to simply copy the main method from the Demo class into your `Bicycle` class and this will still work

```
public class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on 
        // those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```